# Calculate weekly returns and volatility from daily prices in Stata

Tags: stata

I need to calculate, for S&P500 companies, weekly returns and volatility from daily prices and keep the results.

Data:

```
ticker     Date          Price
A          03jan2011     41.88
A          04jan2011     42.00
...
AAPL
```

I use an expression that looks like this (in the same way for volatility):

```
gen return = log(price[_n] / price[1]), by(ticker)
collapse return, by(ticker)
```

But I am not sure what is the correct form to get because some weeks have 4 days, others 5 days.

Comment: Your code compares the price in observation `_n` to the first price in the `ticker` panel. Therefore, for any particular `ticker`, it appears you are comparing, for example, `price` in `26feb2011` to `price` in `03jan2011`. Many of us couldn't say if this is what you seek. The question may also be considered off-topic by some people, as you're only asking if you are doing something in the correct way.

Comment: Please see the Asking section of the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

You said you want weekly returns so what I would do is this:

```
gen weeknumber=wofd(date) //this gives you the week number starting from jan1960
sort ticker date
bysort ticker weeknumber:gen temp=_n
bysort ticker weeknumber:gen temp2=_N
drop if temp!=temp2
drop temp temp2
***Now you have only weekly returns***
gen return = log(price[_n] / price[_n-1]), by(ticker)
```

Comment: Stata weeks don't correspond to weeks used anywhere else, so recommending `wofd()` is likely to be dubious advice. In essence, you are better off defining weeks consistently by a particular day, their starts, ends or middles. For a fuller story, see http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0052 and its sequels in the _Stata Journal_.